# Set a timeout in a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, timeout

I'd like to set a timeout for a promise.

**Error message :**

```
Status is OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.
```

So, to execute the API every seconds, I need to set a timeout in the promise. But with my code below it doesn't worK...

**My code :**

```
CoordinateModel.findAll().then(function(findedCoordinates) {

  var promises = [];

  promises = findedCoordinates.map(function(coordinate) {
    return new Promise(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        return geocoder.geocode(coordinate.address + ' ' + coordinate.postcode + ' ' + coordinate.city + ' ' + coordinate.complementaryAddress).then(function(res) {
          return coordinate.update({
            lng: res[0].longitude,
            lat: res[0].latitude
          }).then(function() {
            console.log(coordinate.name + ' : ' + res[0].longitude + ',' + res[0].latitude);
            return Promise.resolve();
          });
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return Promise.reject();
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log('------ END ------');
  });

});
```

Comment: You need to resolve the `new Promise` that you're returning in the `.map` function, otherwise none of your proimses will ever return.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't work with my code, the `geocode()` function is not executed every one seconds...

Comment: In regards to only processing one request every second, there are a few options, but the most basic one is that the number you give to your `setTimeout` function should INCREASE by 1000 every iteration.

Comment: The way you have it now, all the promises will process at exactly one second.

Comment: The easy way to make it increase by 1000 every iteration is to know that the `.map` function takes an index as a second argument, `.map(function(element, index)) ... setTimeout(f(), 1000*index)`. if you follow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the index in the .map function, and resolving/rejecting the promise appropriately. Use the index in your `setTimeout`

```
promises = findedCoordinates.map(function(coordinate, index) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        return geocoder.geocode(coordinate.address + ' ' + coordinate.postcode + ' ' + coordinate.city + ' ' + coordinate.complementaryAddress).then(function(res) {
          return coordinate.update({
            lng: res[0].longitude,
            lat: res[0].latitude
          }).then(function() {
            console.log(coordinate.name + ' : ' + res[0].longitude + ',' + res[0].latitude);
            resolve();
          });
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
      }, 1000 * index);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the logic is wrong

what the settimeout code does it

it will call all the request at the sametime except it will call after one secs

you can increment the setTimeout every instance like for the first instance it will take 0 sec, for the second instance it will wait for 1 sec, for the instance it will wait for 2 sec,....
by changing `1000 * i` at line 20

```
CoordinateModel.findAll().then(function (findedCoordinates) {

    var promises = [];

    promises = findedCoordinates.map(function (coordinate) {
        return new Promise(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                return geocoder.geocode(coordinate.address + ' ' + coordinate.postcode + ' ' + coordinate.city + ' ' + coordinate.complementaryAddress).then(function (res) {
                    return coordinate.update({
                        lng: res[0].longitude,
                        lat: res[0].latitude
                    }).then(function () {
                        console.log(coordinate.name + ' : ' + res[0].longitude + ',' + res[0].latitude);
                        return Promise.resolve();
                    });
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return Promise.reject();
                });
            }, 1000 * i);
        });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log('------ END ------');
    });

});
```